# How can I identify the gender of my giant gourami?

Tags: fish, aquarium, gender-differentiation, gourami

I find it very difficult to identify the gender of my giant gourami.

Some people told me that the gender will be determined when the giant gourami crosses 3 years of age, is it true? (My giant gourami is 2 years and 6 months old)

Please tell me how to identify the gender of the giant gourami and also please convey me the gender of my fish. The words of people are always different and it is very confusing for me.

Here are a few pictures of my giant gourami fish.

[image: fish]

[image: broken to scale]
[image: unbroken to scale]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Answer (score 3):

According to [Bristol Zoo Gardens](http://www.bristolzoo.org.uk/giant-gourami), the male of this species has more pointed dorsal and anal fins and will have distinct swelling of the forehead when mature. In addition, several sites indicate that the body of the [male is darker](http://www.tankfishtips.com/giant-gourami/) and downplay the forehead. At any rate, the pointedness of the dorsal fin seems to be a commonly agreed upon means of sexing, other signs may be additional indicators to help.

As to your fish, it's really hard to tell from the pictures you posted I'm afraid. I can't get a good look at the dorsal fin, though it appears fairly pointed.

Comment: I've seen the same information, though males might only become darker when they're in breeding mode. Also worth noting that "pointed" might be relative here -- it could be hard to say for sure if you don't have a bunch of others to compare one to.

Comment: @toxotes - Yeah, getting comparative images seems to be surprisingly hard.

Comment: @JohnCavan: Me too read that the dorsal fins are pointed for male, but i was not able to identify that's why i posted the Question,:)

Comment: @SankarGanesh Just FYI, it's not always possible to tell the difference with some fish, unless you see them laying eggs. And of course some fish change back and forth anyway, though I've never heard of gouramis doing that.

Answer (score 1):

after 3 years old, we can sexually identify our giant gourami by checking their lower lip, bottom of pectoral fin etc. male have thicker lower lip and golden colour on the bottom of pectoral fin. female have small face and black colour near pectoral fin..